# How could I add a total value within subplots matplotlib chart at the top right corner where the legend is shown

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am learning to develop charts and visualizations using matplotlib, pandas and plotly.

I have developed a chart from my dataframe using the plt.subplots, plot kind='barh'. The plot projects data correctly, however, I need to also show the total value within  box on the top right corner of the bar chart. Here is my code to project the plt...

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
subset_df_sows['Status'].value_counts().plot(ax=ax,kind='barh')
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
plt.ylabel('SOW Status')
plt.xlabel('Number of SOWs since 01/04/2021')
ax.annotate(r'Total SOWs=', xy=(4,3),va='top')
```

This is how my chart looks upon executing the code

[image]

I need to add a total value within the box at the top right corner where it shows Total SoWs = 10.

How could I do it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the value you want to show simply do:

```py
ax.annotate("Total SOWs="+str(value), xy=(4,3),va='top')
```

Comment: Yes, perfect. I did indeed had the value and it worked. Thank you so much appreciate your help.